# calculate the area of this shape

Tags: geometry, area

It's a rectangle with 2 half elipses joined on the left and right side.

The rectangle itself is 3.55 X 2.54

The width of the whole shape (rectangle with 2 elipses) is 4.195.

Take away the width of the rectangle from the overall width

4.195 - 2.54 = 1.656

1.655 is the width of the 2 elipses. (0.8725 each)

Because I have the width of the 2 elipses as 1.655 when put together and the height as 3.55 can I accurately calculate the the area of the full shape?

Comment: A drawing would help!

Answer (score 1):

The ellipses are the real problem here, the square shouldn't be very hard to tackle.

We have 2 identical half ellipses, giving us one full ellipse. Here's the dimensions if the ellipse:

$1.655 \text{ by }3.55$

The area of the ellipse is then $\pi\times 0.8275\times1.75$

Adding the area of the square gives us
$$\pi\times 1.75\times0.8275+3.55\times2.54=1.448125\pi+9.017\approx13.566$$

Comment: For calculating the elipse do you not use the length of the semi major and minus axis? Ie pi X half height X half width? So it would be pi X 1.75 X 0.8275

Comment: @user158164 you're right, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I did the exact same as you but I'm not sure how accurate it is. Posted it on http://www.boxingscene.com/forums/showthread.php?p=14678633#post14678633 and got a different answer.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/w5f5moq7z/ this is the original question

Comment: @user158164 On your answer you set $R=2.098$ where it actually is $R=2.183$ this has the effect of having the angle off by $6.7$ degrees, and such propagates with the error increasing for each step. Finally this causes the error in your final answer.

Comment: So other than the slight miscalculation with R that I will fix is that the correct method to calculate the area of the shape? I can calculate the area if the shape was a circle as I have the diameter and the scientific notation is not a problem. It's just calculating the area of that shape that threw me. I assumed R was just half of the 4.195 width and thats why I had 2.089

Comment: @user158164 The reason that $R$ is wrong because $4.195$ was wrong, the diagonal is $\sqrt{3.55^2+2.54^2}=4.3651$. Also I'm having a hard time reading your equation for $A$ so I haven't been able to see your wrong $R$ value is the only problem.

Comment: I need to head out for 2hrs to take my son to nursery. Once I come back I'm cracking this. Spent 2 days on it before I decided to ask for some hints. All help so far has been much appreciated